# Installshield, MVVM light MahApps Metro App not working after install

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, installshield

I have plugged a very simple app using **MahApps Metro** for Windows styling and **MVVM Light** for WPF and data binding. Basically the Main Window has 3 datagridviews with 3 Observable Collection properties obtained from a database. I'm using **SQLite and Dapper** and basic CRUD operations, done in some flyouts and metro input dialogs.

Another window called from a button's relay command in Main Window, with some graphics using Modern UI Charts and a third window using 2 datagridViews,  for consulting database info between dates and by activities, also some Create, edit and delete of these records.

In debug and release mode the application works just fine. **My problem arises when I'm trying to create a setup package for test deployment using free InstallShield, in which the installed app and action such as Add an Activity (Create a record in the DB, add it to ActivityList and reload the UI by reload data in dataservice) doesn't work as it does on debug or release**. I don't know the source of the problem because I'm not debugging, but there is a chance I'm not including some necessary file in the application files of the Setup Project.

The VS Solution is available here: https://github.com/brianignacio5/MvvmLightTest1/tree/DeployError

The app, by the way, is in Spanish, but I guess you can understand the architecture. If not I'll gladly translate some of it for ease.

Answer (score 0):

I did not erase the question so maybe someone could have this reference.

First i've depurated installed app with visual studio. Error was SQLite DB was a read-only database.

When you make a Setup project with Install Shield LE, the [INSTALLDIR] need admin privileges (Free version) and you need to give this folder Write permissions (which you can't in free version) so you can write in database.

Hope it helps anyone.